# Cognos logout using Passport Id by java sdk

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cognos

While Using SSO When I login with `&m_passportid` which is generated by Cognos Java SDK it works, but even after I logout it continues to allow user to use same passport ID. Is there any way to invalidate that passport ID issued by Cognos? As there is no way to delete cross domain cookie, so I cannot delete `cam_passport` cookie from my application.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are calling logoff() method of the ContentManagerService, otherwise the id will remain valid until it is timed out.

Comment: Hi DeadSpock, I am aware about that method but it can not delete cookies once set in browser , so once user login with passportId , this logoff method is not able to invalidate cam_passport which already been set in browser

Comment: Issue is specific to cognos version >=10

Comment: You're right the cookie is not deleted, assume it will remain on users browser, however the logoff method invalidates the cookie session value, so next time user tries to access using that cookie, the access should be denied.

Comment: yes deadspock I am facing this issue on single sign off and your explanation works on cognos 8 but still issue with cognos 10, it only checks cam_passport one time while setting not with every request